# Math mode: **! Font OMX/cmex/m/n/6=cmex7 at 6.0pt not loadable: Bad metric (TFM) file

Tags: math-mode, texstudio

i just downloaded the texstudio editor. Now i am directly running into problems. 
Everthing is running fine so far besides the crucial math mode. I typed down the code as follows:

```
\documentclass[11
 pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{}
\title{ }
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
H \cdot x= p
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I tried to compile this but i get the following report:

*

> ```
> **! Font OMX/cmex/m/n/6=cmex7 at 6.0pt not loadable: Bad metric (TFM) file.
> <to be read again> 
>                    relax 
> l.10  \begin{equation}
>
> I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
> so I will ignore the font specification.
> [Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
> You might try inserting a different font spec;
> e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
> ! Math formula deleted: Insufficient extension fonts.
> \endmathdisplay ...badmath \fi \endmathdisplay@a $
>                                                   $\global \let \df@label \@...
> l.12  \end{equation}
>
> Sorry, but I can't typeset math unless \textfont 3
> and \scriptfont 3 and \scriptscriptfont 3 have all
> the \fontdimen values needed in math extension fonts.**
> ```

I have no clue what's going on there so i would be really glad if anybody could help me.

Comment: Welcome! Why do you have a space between `11` and `pt` in the class options? That's not the problem - the code compiles fine for me - but it just seemed odd. How did you install your TeX distribution? Your editor isn't relevant - it is just an editor. Your TeX distribution, however, is.

Comment: on the face of it, it is saying that your font file is corrupt, impossible to say how that happened, but re-installing your tex system is a possible way out.

Comment: Thanks to cfr for your hint with the distribution. I after downloading MikTex and re-installing the editor directory where the distribution resides, david recommended, it worked.
Thank you for your help, Sirs!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments (reinstallation).